# Laravel - Using Models and Controllers appropriately

Tags: php, laravel

In the application I'm working on I have three routes:

```
Route::get('/people-and-teams', 'TeamsController@index');
Route::get('/people-and-teams/{team}', 'TeamsController@show');
Route::get('/people-and-teams/{team}/{person}', 'UserController@show');
```

So essentially you go to a teams page, it lists all the teams, clicking on a specific team loads details about the team and who works there and clicking on a team member gives you a profile for this user.

The tables

- Teams
- Users
- Profiles

The links

- A team has many users
- A user has one profile

As you can see, in the third route I'm considering using `UserController` but is it possible and does it make sense to instead:

1. Get the user information by loading the relationship between teams and users
2. Then get the profile information by loading the relationship between users and profiles, all within the `TeamsController`?

Is there a right way of doing this or am I free to pick and choose which controller to use?

Comment: There's no right way of doing this. You pick the one that makes the most sense for your application.

Comment: There is no real right way, its all mostly opinion based. What makes the most sense to you.

Comment: So there's no harm in using either controller? I just didn't know if it was feasible to go through the team controller, as at that point, all the info I want is user based anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You are always free to use any controller in the routes, if you are not using resource directive...

**Short answer is, if you can directly call a specific user, then do it...**

Always try to avoid calling relationships, cause they all come with additional processing cost.

So performance wise, if on the teams page, you need to call distant relationship to get user_id, than it might better, to call this relationship on specific persons page, cause this will probably be executed not so often.

Please note that, in the real world scenario, it depends on users load.